# How do I set the value of a custom field in Jira Server using the REST API via JRJC?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to use JRJC to create an issue, and I must set a custom field before that is successful. I tried searching for examples, but did not find any.
Here's the code I am using to create the issue:

```
Long testIssueTypeId = getTestIssueTypeId(projectKey);

IssueInputBuilder builder = new IssueInputBuilder()
    .setProjectKey(projectKey)
    .setIssueTypeId(testIssueTypeId)
    .setSummary(summary)
    .setDescription(description);

IssueInput input = builder.build();

return jira.getIssueClient().createIssue(input).claim();
```

To the list of attributes, I need to set a custom field called "Application". In the JSON of a similar issue it appears like this:

```
{
  "self": "https://jira.web.labs.att.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14314",
  "value":"NA:12345",
  "id": "14314",
  "disabled": false
}
```

Here's what I've tried (for another custom field):

```
IssueInputBuilder builder = new IssueInputBuilder()
    .setProjectKey(projectKey)
    .setIssueTypeId(testIssueTypeId)
    .setSummary(summary)
    .setDescription(description)
    .setFieldValue("Test Type", 
       new CustomFieldOption(14314L, null, "Functional", null, null));
```

With this code, I get the following error:

```
RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={Test Type=Field 'Test Type' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
```

What code do I need to add to the IssueInputBuilder to set this field's value? Or is there another, more preferred approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is related with that custom field "Test Type". You are getting that error because whether the "Test Type" field is not in the create/edit page of issue type or the user that you perform has no create/edit permission for that project.

Probably it is the first one. So, you should handle it within workflow or you should place the field to the screen.